# Flash player debugger stopped working

Tags: windows, flash, debugging

Has anybody had Flash player debuuger suddenly stop working for no reason whatsoever.

What I've found so far:
- No exception screens popping up.. in ANY browser. Reinstalled debugger version of flash player, no go.
- Flashbug not showing in Firebug
- No trace calls visible in FlashDevelop
- Flash IDE behaves normal.. all trace calls visible
- Firefox updated about the same time but problem seems to be on a wider scale

This started approximately, on Sunday 8th Januray (or saturday).

Any ideas?

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the below special uninstaller:
  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html#main_Download_the_Adobe_Flash_Player_uninstaller
- Reboot
- Download and install the latest debug version:
- - http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_ax_debug_32bit.exe
- - http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug_32bit.exe
- Ensure that this file exists, otherwise create it:
  "c:\Documents and Settings[user name]\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\flashlog.txt"
- Note that there is a bug in Flash Player right now that when Photoshop is open that the player will not  update logs

I hope this works for you as it did for me!

There's also a thread about this for Win 7 64x at:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3045268

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did these steps when the problem began. They did not work. However, since then everything has started to work again. By itself. I don't know why. But, at least thanks to this problem I found Monster Debugger from demonsters. ;)